# Appropriate preposition in context

Tags: difference, prepositional-phrases

Which prepositional construction would be more/most appropriate?

- Where did you go ***on*** the excursion

or

- Where did you go ***for*** the excursion

Both sounds quite natural to me, but it feels like that there exists a nuance I cannot pinpoint.

Please elaborate on your answer wherever possible. In addition, I think there might be case of US/UK difference.

Finally, is it grammatically correct to rephrase the question to

"Where was the excursion (or trip) to?"

Comment: I can't see a problem or difference between the two.

Comment: Also, Where was your trip to? is good.

Comment: In the U.K. I think we tend to say trip much more than excursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first is more natural, but both could be usable.

> Where did you go **on** the excursion?

using *on* implies an activity. Where you went, etc. This is usually what the response expects.

> Where did you go **for** the excursion?

using *for* implies an occasion, for example "Where did you go *for* your vacation?" There is more emphasis on the activity itself rather than the details.

Comment: And may I please have your view on the grammatically of 'where is the excursion/trip to?' as an alternative?